# Creating a single project containing only components to be used in others angular projects

Tags: angular

I've a need like this:

Project 1: Only reusable UI components

Project 2, 3, 4...: Be capable to import the the things on the Project 1.

So, on the project 2, I could have:

```
import { customTable, customCheckBox} from 'Project 1';
```

Is there some how to do that ?

Comment: You could create a library of reusable components. Some thing like here https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e Ignore `Publish it on npm` section from there.

Comment: https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/01/21/distributing-an-angular-library-aot-ngc-types/

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'Project 1' as dependency of other projects.
Follow these steps

1. Create a `index.ts` file in root directory of 'Project 1' and export everything you want to reuse in another project -

   `export * from './src/app/comp_dir/comp_class'
   export * from './src/app/comp_dir/comp_service'
   . . .
   . . . more ...`
2. Add 'Project 1' as dependency ( inside node_modules )
3. Import components/services in 'Project 2,3,4 ... from 'Project 1'

   `import { comp_class } from 'Project_1'`
4. Use component as you wish.